# Don't have to hit enter in batch

Tags: batch-file, enter

I want to know how to let the user give an input without having to press enter. I saw a youtube video of it happening but I can't figure out how to do it and I can't find out how to do it on any website! Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `choice`. What the following lines will do is it will ask you for input and depending on what input, print different things.

```
@echo off
choice /c sbr /n /m "You peek into the chest and have to choose either [s]word, 
[b]ow or magic [r]od."

if %errorlevel% == 1 echo You pick up the sword and slice the water melon into two 
equal pieces.
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo You pick up the bow and quickscope an arrow at the flower 
vase.
if %errorlevel% == 3 echo You pick up the magic rod and point it at a candle which 
satosfactorily lights up.

pause >nul
```

The /c is just something you have to add, like, if you want there to be alternatives. /n is if you don't want `sbr` to be printed. /m is if you want to add a message, in my example, "You peek into the chest"...

ERRORLEVEL is an envoronment variable, containing what alternative they chose. ERRORLEVEL will always be a number, and depending on which order you put the alternatives (sbr in my example), ERRORLEVEL will change. For example, s is first. This means ERRORLEVEL will be 1 if s is chosen.

There are some deeper stuff you can do with `choice` but you can check them out by yourself with `choice /?`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot!!, Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Just include a carriage return in the command itself. That will have the same effect as pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

From the prompt, execute `choice /?` for all the directions you need.

Comment: choice.exe is available in modern Windows versions.  You will easily find some choice examples in google but the modern version is a little different from the MSdos and Win9x versions.  Much of the code could still work though.